# How to know what GraphLayout was used when Method set to Automatic

Tags: graphs-and-networks, options, implementation-details

I was expecting to get the answer to the above by doing either of the following:

```
Options[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}], GraphLayout]
AbsoluteOptions[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}], GraphLayout]
```

However the result to both is

> GraphLayout->Automatic

How do I find out the optionsetting for `GraphLayout` chosen by the Automatic method?

Comment: I can't prove it, so I won't post an answer, but I do not think there is a way to find out (other than trying all graph layouts and seeing which one looks like the same). If you post a screenshot, I might be able to identify it. It is almost always `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"`, unless the graph small, directed and acyclic, when it is `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`, or if the graph is small, undirected and a tree, when it is `"LayeredEmbedding"`. Built-in graph generators like `GridGraph` often set their own special layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Rasterize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) to do a "visual" comparison with some suspects

```
grR = Rasterize@Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}];

Select[{#, 
    Rasterize@
     Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, GraphLayout -> #]} & /@
  {"CircularEmbedding", 
   "SpiralEmbedding", "SpringEmbedding", "SpringElectricalEmbedding", 
   "HighDimensionalEmbedding", "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
   "LayeredEmbedding"}, #[[2]] === grR &]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, really clever way to compare ... but still hoping there is a direct way to interrogate ...

Comment: It seems, I hoped in vain to find out what underlying option was applied when GraphLayout's setting is Automatic. Your answer however does the trick in an indirect way, and quite creative.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `GraphLayout -> Automatic` typically resolves to one of the following:

- For large graphs, the default is `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"`.
- Small undirected trees up to 49 vertices use `"LayeredEmbedding"`. It looks like this:

  [image]
- Small directed acyclic graphs up to 49 vertices use `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`. It looks like this:

  [image]

This is based on experience. I have no references. You can compare with the images I included above to determine if any of the `Layered...` embeddings are being used. You can manually set a `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"` and see if anything changes to determine if that embedding was used.

If you have a graph which uses neither of these, let me know.

Comment: I did not know there are only two default options, good to know. I did find the type of layout via brute-force (simply try everything and compare) but that was not really the solution approach I was hoping for :). Understand now there seems no way to "interrogate" directly.

Comment: @Sander Three, not two. But I may be wrong. Let me know if you find a counterexample.